# If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, then $\underset{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}}\max (z-x) = ?$

Tags: calculus, inequality

**Question:** If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, then $\underset{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}}\max (z-x) = ?$

$z-x = z - \sqrt{1 - y^2 - z^2} \leq z - \sqrt{1 - z^2}$ $\ \forall \ z \implies y^{*} = 0$. Differentiating and solving it gives $\max(z-x) = \sqrt{2}$.

Can we solve it using inequalities instead of calculus? I feel like we might be able to make use of $(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 = 2 - 2\sum xy = 3 - (\sum x)^2 \leq 3$ somewhere but I fail to deduce anything substantial from it.

Comment: Hint. This locus is a sphere of radius $1$.

Comment: Hint: $(z-x)^2 + (z+x)^2 = 2(z^2+x^2) \le 2$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, I didn't see that.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I thought about it but I couldn't get to the solution from there. I tried the same locus thing for 2D and then that gave me the answer I wrote.

Comment: I think without loss of generality, you may take $y=0$ in the inequality you found. Since, we can do rotations.

Comment: What is $y^*$? And what if $x < 0$ in your equation for  $z - x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with CS inequality:
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)\cdot(1^2+0^2+(-1)^2)\geqslant (x-z)^2$$
$$\implies 1\cdot2 \geqslant |x-z|^2$$
As equality is possible when $x=-z=\pm \frac1{\sqrt2}, y=0$ , this gives the maximum of $|x-z|$ as $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it's exactly how I wanted the solution to be. (I also like the other way suggested as a comment by @achille hui.)

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, then $x^2+z^2\leqslant1$. If you take $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, $y=0$, and $z=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$, then $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $|x-z|=\sqrt2$. On the other hand, since $x^2+z^2\leqslant1$, there are numbers $r\left(=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ and $\theta$ such that $=r\cos\theta$ and $z=r\sin\theta$. Therefore,\begin{align}|x-z|&=r|\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)|\\&=r\sqrt2\left|\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos(\theta)-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin(\theta)\right|\\&=r\sqrt2\left|\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)\cos(\theta)-\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\sin(\theta)\right|\\&=r\sqrt2\left|\cos\left(\theta+\frac\pi4\right)\right|\\&\leqslant r\sqrt2\\&\leqslant\sqrt2.\end{align}So, the maximum of $|x-z|$ is $\sqrt2$.